# getting data from a form using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data from an html form using jquery. I have tried the following but for some reason when I tried to log the data in the console, I keep getting null. What could I be doing wrong ? I want to send the data captured from my form in json format to my servlet. Thanks

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
.vertical-menu {
    width: 200px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form id="register">
<div class="vertical-menu">

</div>
 API Name:<br>
  <input type="text" id = "apiname" name="apiname">
   API ENDPOINT:<br>
  <input type="text" id ="apiendpoint" name="apiendpoint">
  <br>
  API VERSION:<br>
  <input type="text" id="apiversion" name="apiversion">
   ACCESSIBLE:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="internet"> Internet<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="vpn"> VPN<br>


  <br>
    <input type="submit" id="check" name="check" value="Insert">

</form> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "#check", function() { // When HTML DOM "click" event is invoked on element with ID "somebutton", execute the following function...
      event.preventDefault();
      var d = $('register').serialize();
      console.log("d",d);
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "HomeServlet",
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data:d,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log("error");
            },

        });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('#register')`. `#` is missing

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to give proper selector:
`register` is the ID of the form so;

```
$(document).on("click", "#check", function() { // When HTML DOM "click" event is invoked on element with ID "somebutton", execute the following function...
      event.preventDefault();
      var d = $('#register').serialize(); // You had missed # here.
      console.log("d",d);
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "HomeServlet",
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data:d,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log("error");
            },

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Handle submit action on the forms.
$('#register').on('submit', function(e) {

    // Prevent the browser to submit the form (we want to do it manually)
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var formdata = (window.FormData) ? new FormData(form[0]) : null;
    var data = (formdata !== null) ? formdata : form.serialize();
    console.log(data);

    // POST request to server 
    $.ajax({
        url : "URL/TO/SERVER",
        type : "POST",
        data : data,
        // other fields you need
    });
});
```

I think that this is a proper way to achieve what you need. Don't forget to add the event argument to your callback function.